# Browser Image Caching Rules

Tags: image, caching, browser

Do browsers only cache images based upon their file name or do they also include their path?

So, would these two images be cached without conflict...

```
<img src="/images/1/image1.jpg" />
<img src="/images/2/image1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have distinct URLs. resources are named in caches by their full URL.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.